# In pandas, how to assign the result of a groupby aggregate to the next group in the original df?

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas I like to use groupby and an aggregate function, e.g. mean
and then put the results back in the original dataframe, but in the **next** group and not in the group itself. How to do this in a vectorized way?

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
data = {'Group': ['A','A','B','B','B','B', 'C','C', 'D','D'],
        'Value': [1.1,1.3,9.1,9.2,9.5,9.4,6.2,6.4,2.2,2.3]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Group','Value'])

print (df)

  Group  Value
0     A    1.1
1     A    1.3
2     B    9.1
3     B    9.2
4     B    9.5
5     B    9.4
6     C    6.2
7     C    6.4
8     D    2.2
9     D    2.3
```

I like to get this, where each group has the mean value of the previous group.

```
  Group  Value
0     A    NaN
1     A    NaN
2     B    1.2
3     B    1.2
4     B    1.2
5     B    1.2
6     C    9.3
7     C    9.3
8     D    6.3
9     D    6.3
```

I tried this, but this is without the shift to the next group

```
df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy, use `map` on a groupby result:

```
df['Value'] = df['Group'].map(df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean().shift()) 
df
  Group  Value
0     A    NaN
1     A    NaN
2     B    1.2
3     B    1.2
4     B    1.2
5     B    1.2
6     C    9.3
7     C    9.3
8     D    6.3
9     D    6.3
```

---

How It Works

Get the mean

```
df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean()

Group
A    1.20
B    9.30
C    6.30
D    2.25
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Shift it down by 1

```
df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean().shift() 

Group
A    NaN
B    1.2
C    9.3
D    6.3
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Map it back.

```
df['Group'].map(df.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean().shift())  

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.2
3    1.2
4    1.2
5    1.2
6    9.3
7    9.3
8    6.3
9    6.3
Name: Group, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks that is great. Much quicker than my apply solution probably.

Comment: @rudi2013 If your soln uses apply then mine is prolly faster ; )

Comment: Calculated timeit analysis your solution was 1.6X faster than mine. I guess due to `.set_index`, `.reset_index` made my answer slow.

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks for the timeits! Try re-doing the timings without the set and reset index call, it is likely to be much faster. With that you could try convincing the OP to work with that particular column as the index since it leads to faster, more optimized code. Sometimes these little tradeoffs are worth it.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate aggregated [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) of each group value and use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and take advantage of pandas index alignment.

```
df.set_index('Group').assign(value = df.groupby('Group').mean().shift()).reset_index()

  Group  Value  value
0     A    1.1    NaN
1     A    1.3    NaN
2     B    9.1    1.2
3     B    9.2    1.2
4     B    9.5    1.2
5     B    9.4    1.2
6     C    6.2    9.3
7     C    6.4    9.3
8     D    2.2    6.3
9     D    2.3    6.3
```

Comment: Having pandas Index.map automatically handle the mapping is a nice spin. (+1) don't forget the trailing `.reset_index()` because OP may not want the Group index.

Comment: Thank you @cs95 .  Adding `.reset_index`, `pd.Series.map` is also equally good and efficient( upvoted already).